# Escreve-se “da” e “do” em sobrenome com letra minúscula ou maiúscula?

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia, preposições, nomes

Por exemplo: No nome “Joaquim de Carvalho”, o correto é o “de” ser escrito com D minusculo ou maiúsculo?

Comment: Os nomes não são regidos por regra, mas existem tendências. Geralmente, os pronomes e artigos, o que "do" e "da" são, são escritos em minúsculo. Porém, isto não impede de eu me chamar "Gabriel Da Silva".

Comment: Apenas para complementar o comentário do @Schilive; é raro ver o D maiúsculo nesses casos, e, quando eu vejo, eu acho estranho.

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silva_(sobrenome) para exemplos

Comment: FWIW, o Manual de Estilo da Secretaria de Comunicação do Senado brasileiro [determina](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/estilos/nome-proprio): "6. As partículas da, de, di, van, von são escritas com inicial minúscula quando estiverem no meio do nome. Quando iniciarem o nome, porém, escreva-as com letra maiúscula. Por exemplo: Leonardo da Vinci, Vicent van Gogh, Da Vinci, Van Gogh.".

Answer (score 4):

Em terras brasileiras, não existe certo ou errado quando se trata de nomes e sobrenomes.  O correto é a forma como está escrito no documento oficial de identidade, e ponto final.  Sem nenhum estudo estatístico para basear minha resposta, mas trabalhando muitos anos em uma profissão onde vejo os nomes de pessoas (mais de 2000 por ano) escritos conforme foram registrados em cartório, posso afirmar que, no Brasil, as palavras ("e", "de", "da", "do", "das", "dos") quando fazem parte do nome ou sobrenome de uma pessoa, são escritas com letras minúsculas.  Exceções existem, mas devem ser bem menos de 1%.

Comment: Eu não usaria a palavra "correto" para a forma como está nos documentos. É só um registro oficial diante de uma instituição imaginária. Em todos os meus documentos meu nome está inteiramente grafado em maiúsculas e sem nenhuma acentuação, e obviamente não escrevo meu nome assim.

Comment: Só me deparo com essas exceções na Internet, o que me leva a crer que são fruto da desatenção ou mau uso da tecnologia (quando a pessoa digita sem se dar ao trabalho de corrigir), ou a programação é realizada sem pensar no público global (quando o teclado do celular, por exemplo, coloca a primeira letra de um campo em maiúscula automaticamente, ou uma plataforma como o Facebook que FORÇA o início de um sobrenome com letras maiúsculas).

Comment: @WicCaesar   Eu moro e trabalho  no Rio de Janeiro há muitas décadas.  Forneço atestados médicos, atestados de óbito, faço receitas de de medicamentos controlados, e vejo documentos oficiais de identidade há muitos e muitos anos.  Já me deparei com "De" maiúsculo na carteira de identidade algumas vezes, entre milhares de vezes.  Por isso eu disse que exceções existem mas são raras.

Comment: @WicCaesar  O nome correto de uma pessoa é aquele que consta no documento oficial de identidade que, por sua vez, é o nome de registro do nascimento.  Então, Aufredo, Rennato, Lusia, Rutte, Maria Das Graças, João D'Almeida e Enrique, são as formas corretas se as pessoas assim foram registradas.  Não tem discussão, só o judiciário pode autorizar mudança de grafia nesses casos, se julgar adequado.

Comment: Eu nunca nem vi uma carteira de identidade que tenha minúsculas. Até minha certidão de nascimento foi datilografada apenas com maiúsculas.